# Url Rewriting issue

Tags: asp.net

HttpModule class as follows:-

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class RewriterHttpModule : IHttpModule
    {

        public void Init(HttpApplication r_objApplication)
        {
            // Register our event handler with Application object.

            r_objApplication.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(BeginRequest);
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Left blank because we dont have to do anything.
        }

        protected void BeginRequest(object r_objSender,
                                    EventArgs r_objEventArgs)
        {
            // Authenticate user credentials, and find out user roles.
            HttpApplication objApp = (HttpApplication)r_objSender;
            HttpContext objContext = (HttpContext)objApp.Context;

            string fullOrigionalpath = objContext.Request.Url.ToString();

            if (fullOrigionalpath.Contains("/Default/Books.aspx"))
            {
                objContext.RewritePath("/Default.aspx?Category=Books");
            }
            else if (fullOrigionalpath.Contains("/Default/DVDs.aspx"))
            {
                objContext.RewritePath("/Default.aspx?Category=DVDs");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Web.Config file as follows:-

```
<configSections>
        <section name="rewriter" requirePermission="false" 
                     type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />       
    </configSections>
```

```
        <add name="UrlRewriter" type="WebApplication1.RewriterHttpModule, WebApplication1"/>
    </httpModules>
    <rewriter>
        <rewrite url="~/Default/books.aspx" to="~/Default.aspx?category=books"/>
        <rewrite url="~/Default/CDs.aspx" to="~/Default.aspx?category=CDs" />
        <rewrite url="~/Default/DVDs.aspx" to="~/Default.aspx?category=DVDs" />
    </rewriter>
```

Sitemaster Page as follows:-

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

I have the url rewriting working alright but when the default.aspx page is loaded on the browser it is not styled by the css stylesheet. What could be the problem?

Comment: Where are the CSS tags/includes? Without that we can't tell much.

Comment: Inside the head tag the link tag is present for stylesheet

Comment: @Chandan Khatwani: please, edit your question to included that part.

Comment: Thank you guys!!! I just removed the tilded sign(~) from the sitemaster page and the stylesheet is now applied!!! Thanks

Comment: Issue resolved. Needs to be closed.

Comment: You should either upvote and accept the solution that helped you, or post the solution that you found on your own and accept that.  We like to keep questions around instead of closing them, that way they can help others who find them in a Google search later.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link:

[IIS Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite)

And for css/javascript you must use absolute path, like:

```
<script src="../my.js"/><script>
```

will become

```
<script src="/js/my.js"/><script>
```

Something like that.

Forgot to explain.

Suppose in original link  /default.aspx?Category=books
you have

When browser load the page it will look after /mystyle.css

When you put /default/books.aspx (that it will load default.aspx?Category=books)
the browser will look after /default/mystyle.css (but you do not have the default directory and mystyle.css in this directory).

Comment: Buddy. I am asking about why the css is not applied to the resulting page.

Comment: Nope. The stylesheet path is the same as the normal default.aspx

Comment: I created a default folder in my solution and copied the style.css to  it. But I still dont get the right output

Comment: Come on help me buddy. What is the problem ?

Comment: In default.aspx change <link href="style.css" .... /> 
to 
<link href="/mycss_dir/style.css" .... />

Answer (score 0):

Do nothing when requesting script folder like:

```
<if url="^/css/(.+)$">
    <rewrite to="~/$1" processing="stop" />
</if>
```

or just add this to top of rewrite config

```
 <rewrite url="^(/.+(\.gif|\.flv|\.swf|\.png|\.jpg|\.ico|\.pdf|\.doc|\.xls|\.css|\.zip|\.rar|\.js|\.xml|\.mp3)(\?.+)?)$" to="$1" processing="stop" />
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your css path will be changed. have you checked by viewsource?
any way, applied the css in that way:

```
<link href='css/homepage.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

hope this help.

Comment: css path is same as before. It is just not applying the stylesheet

Comment: in which scnerio the css not worked. by defauly the page loaded ,the css worked well and you did click on some link the css is missing right? set path in this way <link href='css/homepage.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />